# For simple rendering: Is OpenCL faster than OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opencl

I need to draw hundreds of semi-transparent circles as part of my OpenCL pipeline.

Currently, I'm using OpenGL (with alpha blend), synced (for portability) using clFinish and glFinish with my OpenCL queue.

Would it be faster to do this rendering task in OpenCL? (assuming the rest of the pipeline is already in OpenCL, and may run on CPU if a no OpenCL-compatible GPU is available).

It's easy replace the rasterizer with a simple test function in the case of a circle. The blend function requires a single read from the destination texture per fragment. So a naive OpenCL implementation seems to be theoretically faster. But maybe OpenGL can render non-overlapping triangles in parallel (this would be harder to implement in OpenCL)?

Comment: "*assuming the rest of the pipeline is already in OpenCL*" Rest of what pipeline are you talking about?

Comment: The processing pipeline in my app. I compute some image with OpenCL, then need to render these circles, then have to process again with OpenCL.

Comment: If you can call rasterization or raycasting simple. I don't know many who would argue implementing either of these things constitutes simple rendering given a specialized API that does it for you as the alternative.

Comment: This is so platform dependent it hurts my eyes.

Comment: @Andreas, It's not possible in my case to optimize and maintain two different code paths, to support the two different options. Especially since Nicol Bolas's solution already provides an efficient solution in OpenCL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odds are good that OpenCL-based processing would be faster, but *only* because you don't have to deal with CL/GL interop. The fact that you have to execute a `glFinish/clFinish` *at all* is a bottleneck.

This has nothing to do with fixed-function vs. shader hardware. It's all about getting rid of the synchronization.

Now, that doesn't mean that there aren't *wrong* ways to use OpenCL to render these things.

What you *don't* want to do is write colors to memory with one compute operation, then read from another compute op, blend, and write them back out to memory. That way lies madness.

What you ought to do instead is effectively build a tile-based renderer internally. Each workgroup will represent some count of pixels (experiment to determine the best count for performance). Each invocation operates on a single pixel. They'll use their pixel position, do the math to determine whether the pixel is within the circle (and how much of it is within the circle), then blend that with a local variable the invocation keeps internally. So each invocation processes *all* of the circles, only writing their pixel's worth of data out at the very end.

Now if you want to be clever, you can do culling, so that each work group is given only the circles that are guaranteed to affect at least some pixel within their particular area. That is effectively a preprocessing pass, and you could even do that on the CPU, since it's probably not that expensive.